# How to answer a logarithm question

Tags: logarithms

Can anyone please show me how to solve this question step by step?  $x$ should equal 60.
$$\log_2 x - \log_2 5 = 2 + \log_2 3$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Use rules like $\log a - \log b = \log (a/b)$, $\log a + \log b=\log (a\cdot b),$ and $\log (a^n)=n \log a$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for the welcome, I was able to solve the first few steps but I was stuck, your answer below helped me solve it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

$$\log_2x-\log_2 5=\log_2 (x/5)$$

$$2+\log_2 3=\log_2 4+\log_2 3=\log_2 12$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_2 x - \log_2 5 = 2 + \log_2 3$$

Using both sides as a power of $2$,
\begin{align}&2^{\log_2 x - \log_2 5} = 2^{2 + \log_2 3}\\
\implies &\frac{2^{\log_2 x}}{2^{\log_2 5}} = 2^2 \cdot  2^{\log_2 3}\\[1ex]
\implies &\frac{x}{5} = 4\cdot 3 \\
\implies& x = 60
\end{align}